# Does screen bind CTRL+T?

Tags: screen

I bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in Vim.

But when I do it in Vim, it appears my arrow keys don't work as normal under screen.

How do I bind Screen's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> function to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^T is not normally bound by screen. If it would, hitting ^V^T in bash would not produce ^T. Check your screen configuration as to where you and/or your provider of the screen installation has annoyingly set ^t.

Comment: Ubuntu was the provider, it seems this issue was known by the author of Command-T and offered alternative keys to the arrow keys. You're right, it's not a Ctrl+T thing.'